# Зачем Pixel perfect верстка

Tags: html, css, frontend, photoshop, layout

Зачем писать макет pixel perfect? Я так понимаю для этого используется Position: relative И отрицательные margin. Это же от одной до трех лишних строк иногда на каждый блок! Это, наверное, плохо влияет на скорость загрузки файла и тд. Да еще и столько мороки и реально скучной работы верстальщику. Объясните свое видение и необходимость ее использования, и используете ли вы ее в работе? Спасибо.

Comment: Низачем не нужно и в реальности всё равно недостижимо. Впрочем вы неправильно понимаете pixel perfect

Comment: @AlexeyTen в чем состоит правильное понимание?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pixel Perfect - это стандарт, согласно которому сверстанный блок или страница должен в точности отвечать макету дизайна, вплоть до пикселя (отсюда и название "идеальный пиксель"). Допустимые погрешности различаются в разных компаниях, придерживающихся этого стандарта - где-то это 1-2 пикселя, где-то до 5, обычно погрешность по вертикали допустима больше, чем по горизонтали. Для достижения этого используются различные плагины, например PerfectPixel для Chrome, позволяющие наложить скриншот дизайна на страницу браузера и таким образом подогнать результат.

Относительно использования position: relative и прочего - вы не правы. Пиксель-перфект - это техническое требование к верстке, а не способ ее реализации. Вполне можно добиться идеального совпадения с макетом и без использования костылей вроде отрицательных марджинов.

Однако зачем это надо в принципе - вопрос риторический. ПиксельПерфект как идеология - родом из тех времен, когда сайты верстались под конкретные разрешения. Дизайнер давал три макета: для десктопа, для планшетов и для мобильных, и требовалось добиться полного совпадения во всех случаях. Но сейчас слишком много устройств и разрешений, кроме того, в разных браузерах страницы могут отображаться чуть по-разному - например, из-за особенностей рендеринга шрифтов. Конечно, добиться пиксель-перфект можно, если заказчик на этом настаивает, если он хорошо платит и если вам не жалко своих глаз. Лично я отклоняю любые заказы или вакансии, где pixel perfect находится в обязательных требованиях (что все еще встречается достаточно регулярно). Но многие верстальщики когда-то научились верстать именно так, им комфортно, а заказчик-перфекционист счастлив. Кроме того, для заказчика это иногда единственная возможность проверить качество верстки, если сам он верстать не умеет. 
Использовать ли этот стандарт на практике - ваш личный выбор. Технических преимуществ в функционировании сайта он никаких не дает.

Answer (score 2):

> Зачем писать макет pixel perfect?

Это атавизм из тех времен, когда один и тот же элемент браузеры отображали каждый через свою собственную ж..., а заказчики упорно игнорировали этот факт.

-- Да, сударь, дизайнер забацал красивую картиночку - извольте в точности так сделать. И, да, мне плевать на то, что в системе шрифт тонкий и резкий - в макете же нафотошоплено прикольненько-мутно-пушисто, значит и тут так подавайте. Css для задания параметров отображения шрифтов начнут разрабатывать только лет через пять? А "мэнэ цэ не е...е"!